# Getting the error in openvpn repo while running command apt-get update

Tags: apt

I am getting the following error while running command "apt-get update":
E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Can someone please help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems something went wrong. Redo these commands again.

```
# wget must be available. If wget is not installed and apt update is broken skip apt update in the next line.
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools

wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list'

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install openvpn-as
```

Comment: Running the first command it shows  the same error as mentioned above. I think I cannot run apt command without fixing that file. Please suggest some other workaround.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Just skip the first line.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Now I am getting the following error while executing the second command:


"/bin/bash: echo "deb /http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list: No such file or directory"

Comment: Updated. It's seems you are absolutely not able to read command manuals.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is taken from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update

The error indicates a malformed entry in a source file, which causes the update process to abort. To fix it, you have to either fix the entry (if you know what the right entry should look like) or remove it altogether (that's what I'm going to describe, as it's the fastest way to enable you to update your system again).

First, you need to open the file containing the bad entry. The filename is given in the error message, in your example /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list. Open a terminal, and type

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list
and press Enter. After entering your password, you should now see the file opened in the text editor nano.

Now you need to locate the malformed entry. It should be on the line number given in the error message - in your case that would be line 1.

This line should be incomplete and start with the unknown type the update process is complaining about (here ain). Just delete the whole line, and save/close the file with Ctrl+X.

That's it. You should now be able to successfully run the update process.

Comment: Deleting the first line does not work. Once I delete the first line it shows the same error (meaning error in second line). Tried deleting the second line as well but it doesn't work. Please suggest some other workaround